# Is there a shutdown / energy savings mode that allows the pc to download windows store apps in the background?

Tags: windows-10

I've got a quite a queue of pretty large apps (XBox Gamepass) that I want to download. Is there a way I can make my PC inaccessible & save as much energy as possible while they download?

I'm on a Windows 10 1903 Desktop.

Ty for your help!

Comment: Just unplug the monitor.

Comment: No, I'm using a dedicated GPU, the idle load is quite high

Answer (score 0):

The "Idle" task is just for bookkeeping and means doing nothing.
A high count means that there are long periods when the computer is not doing anything,
just waiting for something to start.

"Idle" doesn't use any energy, so don't worry about it